# Favorite Tags Synonyms

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-watching

I decided to test out tag synonyms and favorite tags, so I added [threads](/questions/tagged/threads) to my favorites. When [threads](/questions/tagged/threads) is clicked on, it opens to [multithreading](/questions/tagged/multithreading). However, in the question queue, all questions marked [multithreading](/questions/tagged/multithreading) don't have the "favorite glow". I suggest one of two things:

- make synonyms of favorite tags "glow"
- make tags that are synonyms of other tags change to the main tag when they are in the favorite tags list (ie when [threads](/questions/tagged/threads) is added to the favorites list, automatically change it to [multithreading](/questions/tagged/multithreading), but do something about already existing favorites lists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions under favorite tags are highlighted **client-side**, meaning the question list itself isn't transmitted to you with the favorites already styled appropriately. A script on the client-side adds the highlighting to all the questions that match, and similarly fades or hides any questions which are ignored.

Therefore, the script doesn't *know* what tags are even synonyms of another tag. The favorite and ignored tags have always been completely denormalized. The tag doesn't even have to exist. Bottom line - no server-side checks are ever done on those tags - you can enter *whatever* you want.

Your only viable solution here is to just use the correct master tag when you realize the tag you entered is actually a synonym.

There is, however, a nice hint that a tag you're selecting is a synonym. In the drop-down box that suggests matching tags, there will be an `(s)` where the number of questions using the tag should be - that means it's a synonym of a master tag and you should probably look into that. Note this only works for synonyms which have been merged into their master tag - if the synonym is still used on old questions, it will still display that number.

Comment: So, why not automatically changed added tags to the synonym?

Comment: @Quincunx Because that would require sending another call to the server just to check a tag, wherein the vast majority of cases it would not result in anything informative. The drop-down list that it displays is just rendered HTML of matching tags returned by the server. It doesn't return a bunch of information about those tags - just plain HTML.