# Add tags by synonym on favorites

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-watching

When I type and click a synonym when trying to add a favorite tag, I get the message

> "tagname does not exist on this site."

I received this message when trying to add `vscode` on Stack Overflow and `block-designs` on Mathematics.

The behavior I'd expect would be:

- The synonym is added and the master tag is searched 
  or
- The master tag is added

Especially on Mathematics, the tag synonyms are not obvious and it is reasonable that I'd know a synonym but not the master tag. It isn't hard to find it out but I was on mobile at the time.

[This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217565/favorite-tags-synonyms) seems to indicate that adding synonyms used to be possible if not fully supported.